# Automate traversing a directory in Linux?

Tags: bash, shell-script, centos

Currently, I am doing full manual work.

```
find /home/bash_cookbook/bash_cookbook/glassfish/domains/blog/logs -mtime +7 -type f -name 'application.log_*' -exec rm {} \;
```

It takes me 1 hour to just type all the directory name that I want to traverse.

**The problem?**

There are 100+ servers,20 different domains in each server each have different name of the domains. A clever approach I've thought of is to exclude some directories instead of include all of them. As some of them contains some domains such as "backup" which I don't need to touch.

But I didn't get how to achieve it.

---

Another clever trick that I can think of is this.

```
find /home/bash_cookbook/bash_cookbook/glassfish/domains/$domains_except_excluded_domains/logs -mtime +7 -type f -name 'application.log_*' -exec rm {} \;
```

For that I need domains_except_excluded_domains variable which needs to include all the domains that I want to exclude. How could this be achieved?

Comment: You really need to use fzf. Also have a look at this: https://github.com/mgunyho/tere

Comment: Installing additional software in server for a small reason like this is not preferred at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using `bash` or another shell that supports arrays you could list the set of domains to be included for processing:

```
#!/bin/bash
incDomains=('blog' 'news' 'webmail' …)

for domain in "${incDomains[@]}"
do
    echo "Considering $domain"
    find "/home/bash_cookbook/bash_cookbook/glassfish/domains/$domain/logs" -mtime +7 -type f -name 'application.log_*' -delete
done
echo "Done"
```

I've guessed where the `$domain` variable should be interpolated into your `find` path. Move it around as necessary.

You can use something similar to *exclude* domains if you are sure you will be able to enumerate them safely. This approach starts with a list of the domains to be excluded, converts them to an associative array (hash) for quick lookup, and then iterates across the set of domain directories skipping any that are in the hash:

```
#!/bin/bash
excDomains=('blog' 'news' 'webmail' …)

declare -A excDomainsH
for domain in "${excDomains[@]}"; do excDomainsH[$domain]=1; done

for domainPath in "/home/bash_cookbook/bash_cookbook/glassfish/domains"/*
do
    domain="${domainPath##*/}"
    [[ "${excDomainsH[$domain]}" -eq 1 ]] && continue

    echo "Considering $domain"
    find "$domainPath/logs" -mtime +7 -type f -name 'application.log_*' -delete
done
echo "Done"
```

In both cases I would *strongly recommend* that you replace `-delete` with `-print` until you are sure the code works as expected. If your implementation of `find` does not have `-delete` consider using `-exec rm -f {} +` instead (note the `+` on the end)

Comment: I'm sorry, but I forgot to mention another constraint. The logs of various domains need to be deleted in different ages. example, some logs should be deleted if they're 30 days old.

Comment: @barnyard9 how could that possibly work with your last paragraph that talks about having the set of directories to be excluded from processing?

Comment: Can you take a look at my answer? And help me improve it? AFAIK "ls" parsing isn't recommended.

Comment: I've answered your question. I rarely critique other people's answers in my own answer, preferring to address the question directly

Answer (score 1):

For excluding whole directories, one option would be negatively matching a path:

```
find ! -path '*exclude1*' ! -path '*exclude2*' ...
```

In contrast to `-name`, `-path` may include slashes and does not treat slashes specially.

If your main problem is speed, the reason might not be too many search directories, but rather `-exec rm {}\;` calling `rm` once per file. Simply replace it with `-delete`. Also have a read in `man find` regarding the difference between  `-exec command {}\;` and `-exec command {} +`, where the latter will use as many of the results as the command argument list as possible.

Answer (score 0):

This is my attempt at this problem.

## Script

```
#!/bin/bash
given_path=/home/techyman/glassfish4/glassfish/domains
excluded_folder=x
for each in $(ls $given_path); do
    if [ "$excluded_folder" = "$each" ]; then
        echo "This is x"
        continue
    else
        echo "this is not x"
        cd $given_path/$each/logs
        echo "This is $PWD"
    fi
done
```

## What it does

- This goes to given path.
- Does a listing by  ls
- If that ls equals to excluded folder, it'll skip it with that continue statement
- Else it goes inside logs directory and does some actions.

Update:

```
#!/bin/bash
given_path=/home/techyman/glassfish4/glassfish/domains
excluded_folder=x
for each in "$given_path"/*; do
    if [ "$excluded_folder" = "$each" ]; then
        echo "This is x"
        echo "$PWD"
        continue
    else
        echo "this is not x"
        echo "$PWD"
        cd $each/logs
        # echo "This is $PWD"
        # echo "This is $x"
    fi
done
```

## Update

```
#!/bin/bash

given_path=/home/techyman/glassfish4/glassfish/domains
excluded_folder="x"
function clear_log() {
    cd "$each"
    echo "$PWD"
    find . -mtime +"$1" -name "*.log" -exec rm -f {} \;
    #echo "$2"
    #echo "$1"
}
for each in "$given_path"/*; do
    if [ "$each" = "$given_path/$excluded_folder" ]; then
        echo "$each"
        #echo "This is x"
        #echo "Do nothing"
        continue
    else
        #echo "this is not x"
        #echo "$each"
        #case statement goes here
        case $each in
        *a)

            echo "This is a"
            clear_log 7 "$each"
            ;;
        *b)
            echo "This is b"
            clear_log 4 "$each"
            ;;
        *c)
            echo "This is c"
            clear_log 5 "$each"
            ;;
        *d)
            echo "This is d"
            clear_log 6 "$each"
            ;;
        *e)
            echo "This is e"
            clear_log 8 "$each"
            ;;
        esac
    fi
done
```

Comment: Sharing knowledge: [Bash pitfall number one](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29).

Comment: what if i quote "$given_path", ls "$given_path"

Comment: yea, I updated with new code.